# Sympy Inverse a function: y = ax+b into x = (y-b)/a

Tags: python, sympy

This should be easy, and hopefully doable in Sympy.

I have a function: *Y = 0.05*X + 0.15*, which I define using Sympy:

```
from sympy import *
Y = 0.05*X + 0.15
```

How do I get the inverse, where I express X as a function of Y:

```
X = (Y-0.15)/0.15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `solve` function, but first, put your equation in the form `f(x,y)=0`:

```
Y = 0.05*X + 0.15
==> 0.05*X + 0.15 - Y = 0
```

So, you can solve it using:

```
 solve( 0.05*X + 0.15 - Y, X)
```

Which will give the solution:

```
[20.0*Y - 3.0]
```

**Alternatively,** you can solve the equation directly using the `Eq` function (which is used to define a symbolic equality):

```
solve( Eq(Y, 0.05*X + 0.15), X)
```

which will give the same answer:

```
[20.0*Y - 3.0]
```